Needing to ignore filter on a visual when calculating percentage onto another visual
this seems like it should be a simple task on the surface but I can't get my head wrapped around this one.
I have a visual bar chart (Chart A) showing the total number of prescriptions sent to various pharmacies.  On another bar chart visual (Chart B) I show the individual providers and their percentage of the total prescriptions sent to each of those pharmacies.
The way it behaves now, which is expected out of the gate is if I select say, Pharmacy C from the Chart A, then in Chart B will show each provider and their percentage share of prescription sent to Pharmacy C.  For example, if Pharmacy C received 1000 total scripts and provider A sent 250 of them, their respective percentage would be 25%. Makes sense.
However, I have received a request to not show the providers percentage share of the selected Pharmacy, but instead the percentage of their total scripts (to all pharmacies) that are sent to the selected pharmacy, in this case Pharmacy C. So for this same example, the provider still sent 250 scripts to Pharmacy C, but they want to know what percentage that is of their total scripts sent to any Pharmacy.  So, if Provider sent 2000 total scripts to all pharmacies and sent the 250 to Pharmacy C, it would then show that 12.5% of their total scripts were sent to Pharmacy C.
What I have been trying is creating a measure to do this calculation using the total number of scripts written to all pharmacies per provider, however anytime I select a specific pharmacy from the Chart A, it still filters the providers total script count just that selected pharmacy.  For the calculation of total scripts I want it to ignore the selected pharmacy and count all scripts sent by the provider, regardless of pharmacy.  i have attempted using the various CALCULATE and filter functions but I can't seem to figure this one out.
I apologize, this is the best way that I can explain it.

Look at using REMOVEFILTERS.
Suggest creating these three measures - note for the second one, you need to remove "filter context" on Pharmacy not Provider:
Prescription Count =
  DISTINCTCOUNT('Rx Data'[PrescriptionID])

Total Provider Prescriptions = 
  CALCULATE(
    [Prescription Count],
    REMOVEFILTERS('Rx Data'[Pharmacy]) // or ALLEXCEPT('Rx Data', 'Rx Data'[Provider])
  )

Provider Percent =
  DIVIDE(
    [Prescription Count],
    [Total Provider Prescriptions]
  )

Data table and result:


Thanks for the response but either I applied your suggestion incorrectly or it wasn't what I needed.  If you can, please check these two images out.  The first image shows no filters applied to the top left visual, therefore it shows all Rx's counted.  In the bottom left visual it shows the total Rx's sent by provider A, then to the right it shows the percentage of all Rx's (8740) that were sent by Provider A.  In the second image, I click on Pharmacy C in the top left visual to apply the filter.  https://imgur.com/a/W2A8lCn

...Here you can see how many Rx's were sent to Pharmacy C by Provider A (123) and then the percentage of all Pharmacy C Rx's (709) that were sent by Provider A.  What I would like to show in the bottom right chart is the percentage of Rx's sent from Provider A to Pharmacy C (121) compared to Provider A's total Rx's, sent to all pharmacies (1011).  I hope this helps, thanks again for even looking at this!

Update your question with the DAX measures your are using.

For the bottom right chart, "Percent by Provider" I have been using the following measure:  Provider Percent = COUNT('Rx Data'[PrescriptionID])/(CALCULATE(count('Rx Data'[PrescriptionID]),ALL('Rx Data'[Provider])))

See updated answer above, try with the three measures. Note that you need to remove filter or ALL on Pharmacy, not Provider.

Thanks Sam.  I created the measures you stated above but for some reason both the 'Total Provider Prescriptions' and 'Prescription Count' is giving me the same value, therefore of course the 'Provider Percent' is always 100%.  This is same issue that I have been running into where the nominator and denominator are returning the same value.

See image above as a result. Perhaps you have other factors at play. Try replacing REMOVEFILTERS(...) with ALLEXCEPT('Rx Data', 'Rx Data'[Provider])

Sam, I think we are getting close.  I replaced the REMOVEFILTERS('Rx Data'[Pharmacy]) with ALLEXCEPT('Rx Data', 'Rx Data'[Provider]) and it is giving me a new value for the Total Provider Prescriptions.  The only issue now is it is not keeping the date filter in tact.  That is my fault as I didn't mention that I had a date slicer involved, very sorry.

Simply add the Date column to the ALLEXCEPT... ALLEXCEPT('Rx Data', 'Rx Data'[Provider], 'Rx Data'[Date]). As the name implies, give me all rows but keep the context on the following columns (ie for the same Provider and for the dates)

Shoot...so adding the date (in my case the column is called [CreatedWhen]) results in the same value as the Prescription count again.  I am guessing there is something else going on because what you are suggesting makes total sense, so I am not sure why it is not behaving as expected.

you can try to turn off the visual interaction
visual interaction
